# pipe result of elisp function to a shell command

Tags: evil, shell

I wanna pipe the output of an elisp function (`emacs-version`) to a shell command (`xclip`). How can I do this?

I accept vanilla emacs and evil solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```el
(with-temp-buffer
  (emacs-version t)
  (call-process-region (point-min) (point-max) "foo"))
```

It creates a temp buffer, inserts the output of `emacs-version` into the temp buffer (the `t` argument of `emacs-version`) and then calls the script `foo` passing it the contents of the buffer on its `stdin`. You may have to season to taste.

To call `foo` with arguments, you need to read the doc string of `call-process-region` (do `C-h f call-process-region RET`). It takes a bunch of optional arguments that it interprets followed by any number of optional string arguments that it passes to the script as *its* arguments:

> (call-process-region START END PROGRAM &optional DELETE BUFFER DISPLAY
> &rest ARGS)
>
> ...
>
> Send text from START to END to a synchronous process running PROGRAM.
>
> ...
>
> Remaining arguments ARGS are passed to PROGRAM at startup as command-line arguments.

So you need to change the above like this:

```el
(with-temp-buffer
  (emacs-version t)
  (call-process-region (point-min) (point-max) "foo" nil nil nil "-i" "-h"))
```

And again, depending on your needs, you may have to season to taste.

Comment: this works almost perfectly. If I could call "foo" with arguments like ```foo -i -h``` it would be perfect

Comment: You can: see the doc string of `call-process-region`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want(?):

```bash
❯ emacs --batch --eval '(prin1 (emacs-version))' | xclip
```

How about this:

```lisp
(async-shell-command (format "echo '%s' | xclip" (emacs-version)))

;;; The following freezes don't know why...

(shell-command-to-string (format "echo '%s' | xclip" (emacs-version)))
```

Comment: I can use this, though I would prefer to do it from a running emacs, inside the graphical interphase

Comment: @honestSalami Edited. See if it matches your needs.

Comment: I've tried both async and shell. async executes well as you wrote it, but it fails with xclip. shell freezes and I must stop the process with ```C-g```. But I'm sure its not your fault. I think emacs and xclip do not play nice together.

Comment: since you installed xclip, can you tell me if you use evil mode? I'm submitting an error just about xclip freezing over and it'd be nice to know if its evil mode or emacs itself that has trouble with xclip

Comment: @honestSalami Sorry, I was being misleading before. I've deleted the previous comment. (I see. Beyond my capabilities it seems. One more option just to put it out there: run terminal inside emacs with sth like vterm. Then it's possible to use elisp to generate & automatically run stuff in terminal instead of typing it manually. )

Comment: @honestSalami I've double checked once again. `async` WORKS and `shell-..` freezes. I do use evil, btw (More specifically, spacemacs). This issue has nothing to do with evil. I've checked with `emacs -Q` and observe the same.